# Problems with USB goflex 2 TB

Tags: linux, centos, usb-drive, fsck, fdisk

I am using CentOS 5.5 and have been using cpio to write backups to a 2 TB GoFlex USB drive. This drive worked great for over a year, but am now running into a problem and not sure what to do.

When cpio is executing, I see files it's writing flying by on the screen and eventually, it end up with a Read-only file system error at different spots during the backup.

CPIO error: 'cpio: write error: Read-only file system' Result code = 256

Copying a large file results in a 'Read-only file error'

For example: cp: writing `/goflex/d1/ssi/daily/tophat_bkup_201307172000.cpio': Read-only file system

After receiving the error, I run '/sbin/fsck.ext3 -y /dev/sda1' on the drive and it recovers the journal and cleans the file system.

Sometimes I can copy a large file to it without problems, other times it dies with the error above within minutes.

Any ideas??

Bad drive??

Something else I should try??

Tried reformatting the hard drive with fdisk (delete old partition) and formatting it again with '/sbin/mkfs -t ext3 /dev/sda1' but...As soon as I tried backing up to it again, I receive the error above.. Arggg!!!

Thx!!!

UPDATED:

smartctl -H /dev/sda

smartctl 5.42 2011-10-20 r3458 [i686-linux-2.6.18-348.4.1.el5PAE] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
Please note the following marginal Attributes:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   056   042   045    Old_age   Always   In_the_past 44 (0 14 48 28 0)

smartctl -t short /dev/sda - complete without any errors

Running 'smartctl -t long /dev/sda' now but this should take a while..

Results:

Extended offline always aborts.  No sure what aborted by host means but my guess is
that it found something it didn't like on the disk.  Not a very detailed report.

smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda
smartctl 5.42 2011-10-20 r3458 [i686-linux-2.6.18-348.4.1.el5PAE] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours) LBA_of_first_error

1  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%     15189

2  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%     15189

3  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%     15188

4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15186

5  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%     15186

6  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%     15186

7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15186

Comment: What are the SMART test results? It ain't wise to use external hard drives for backups; hard disks fail regularly (and unexpectedly).

Comment: Never used the SMART utility..Reading the man page for smartd.conf to figure it out..We do tape and usb hard drive backups so not worried about failures...

Comment: I have had problems with multiple Seagate Goflex drives running under Linux.  Every one of them has failed to respond after successfully running for a period of time.  No problems once I changed over to using drives by Western Digital.

Comment: thanks yoonix! I sure I'll have to replace this drive and will try a Western Digital drive instead.

Comment: Good page describing how to use smartctl here: http://blog.shadypixel.com/monitoring-hard-drive-health-on-linux-with-smartmontools/

Comment: You only showed the temperature attribute.  The ones to look at are offline_uncorrectable, relocated, and pending sector counts.  Also when you get such an error the first thing to check is `dmesg`.